# how to customise FSCalendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, fscalendar

I am using FSCalendar https://github.com/WenchaoIOS/FSCalendar I have a button in my VC and FSCalendar in UIView If I click on the button I need to show the Current date(something like the google calendar app) how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the calendar selectDate with today's date in the button action. like below:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
[calendar setDate: today];
```

When you tap the button this will scroll to today with animation and select it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have 2 arrays as - eventDateArray consisting event NSDates & another array as colouredDateArray having NSDate's to be coloured. How can I achieve the same ? Please reply.           https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/issues/275

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the month of today.

```
 calendar.currentPage = [NSDate date];
```

If you want to 'select' today and show the month of today

```
[calendar selectDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: I have 2 arrays as - eventDateArray consisting event NSDates & another array as colouredDateArray having NSDate's to be coloured. How can I achieve the same ? Please reply.           https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/issues/275

Comment: Hello, I want to remove the dates out of range for the current month in the same FSCalendar. For eg - date range is 21st May to 20 June, so I want to show the calendar only for these dates. Is it possible with the library? I would be happy to post another question for this to answer but was curious if it possible quickly?

Comment: Link To my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61928955/show-only-dates-in-the-mentioned-range-for-the-month-using-fscalendar

Answer (score 1):

```
Button Action：    

- (void)backToToday {
// scroll to page date
self.currentPageDate = self.today;
// default selected date
self.selectedDate = self.today;

self.calendar.currentPage = self.currentPageDate;
[self.calendar selectDate:self.selectedDate scrollToDate:NO];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please help me also with my question?
Link To my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61928955/show-only-dates-in-the-mentioned-range-for-the-month-using-fscalendar

Answer (score 0):

**Create FSCalendar Programmatically and Customise**

```
var calendar: FSCalendar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    calendar = FSCalendar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.calendarView.frame.width, height: self.calendarView.frame.height))
        calendar.alpha = 1
        calendar.center = calendarView.center

    calendar.headerHeight = 0
        calendar.placeholderType = .none
        calendar.appearance.weekdayTextColor = .lightGray    //   weekday text color
        calendar.appearance.titleDefaultColor = .white   //   active dates color
        calendar.appearance.titleSelectionColor = .black    //   selected date text color
        calendar.appearance.titleTodayColor = .black    //  todays date text color
        calendar.appearance.todayColor = .white   // todays date circle color
        calendar.appearance.selectionColor = .lightGray   //   date selection color
        calendarView.addSubview(calendar)
        calendarCurrentPageDidChange(calendar)
}
```

To display current month name from FSCalendar

```
func calendarCurrentPageDidChange(_ calendar: FSCalendar) {
        let currentPageDate = calendar.currentPage
        let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: currentPageDate)
        let monthName = DateFormatter().monthSymbols[month - 1].capitalized      // Get current month name to display separately 
        monthLbl.setTitle(monthName, for: .normal)
  }
```

FSCalendar Delegate functions

```
func maximumDate(for calendar: FSCalendar) -> Date {
        var dateComponents:DateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.month = 12            // maximum month to display in calendar
        let currentCalander:Calendar = Calendar.current
        return currentCalander.date(byAdding:dateComponents, to: Date())!
}
    
func minimumDate(for calendar: FSCalendar) -> Date {
        var dateComponents:DateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.month = 0             // minimum month to display in calendar
        let currentCalander:Calendar = Calendar.current
        return currentCalander.date(byAdding:dateComponents, to: Date())!
}

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
        self.scrollToDate(date.date)
 }
```

Event list using FSCalendar - Show and Hide Calendar using UIButton

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75887245/15716725