# Show only dates in the mentioned range for the month using FSCalendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, calendar, fscalendar

I am using [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar). I am able to achieve everything except below point:

1) I want to remove dates for the collection view which are not in the range of the calendar. For Eg. My calendar date ranges from the current date to the past 30 days from the current date. In today's scenario from **20th April to the 21st of May**. So, I **don't want to show dates from 1st to 19th of April and 22nd to the month end of May**. The logic written in the library is a bit complicated for me to get it done.

I have already shared the GitHub link for the code to check out and maybe help me. I haven't shared any of my code as it is not a single file change that is needed, it includes multiple files, and that why I shared the link to the library repo. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: link to access your prj ?

Comment: @King.lbt: The link I added is for the library I am using, If you download that, you will definitely have an idea what I am looking for. I can not share the link for my project as its private and I didn't share any code as It's not a single file code I can share to show what all I tried.

Comment: I have implemented this framework one time. I understand that you want the current day is always the first day of the UI right ?

Comment: As my range of calendar is from current date to past 30 days, so my first date of the calendar should be the past 30th date. But I guess you get what I want.

Comment: If this helps to understand my requirement: My calendar date ranges from the current date to the past 30 days from the current date. In today's scenario from 20th April to the 21st of May. So, I don't want to show dates from 1st to 19th of April and 22nd to the month end of May.

Answer (score 1):

After exploring more detail in code in FSCalendar, I figure that you can do it. But it's mean you have to make some changes for the library.
First in `FSCalendarExtension`,

```
- (nullable NSDate *)fs_firstDayOfMonth:(NSDate *)month
{
    if (!month) return nil;
    NSDateComponents *components = [self components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:month];
    components.day = today;
    return [self dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

This will get the first day of the month, you have to set it back to the current date. As well as modified all the following functions :

```
- (nullable NSDate *)fs_firstDayOfWeek:(NSDate *)week
- (nullable NSDate *)fs_lastDayOfWeek:(NSDate *)week
- (NSInteger)fs_numberOfDaysInMonth:(NSDate *)month
```

I mean that's a lot of changes. And you have to change code for library, A better way for you is creating your own calendar. It would be better.

Comment: Thank you so much for getting the time to look at my problem and getting a solution for it. I finally did make it work using the same FSCalendar somehow :P. It required me to write my method and then implement it. Appreciate your efforts man :)

I might add an answer soon with all the changes I have done.

Comment: If anyone wants the same and stuck and see this, let me know, I might be able to help them.

Answer (score 0):

Base to the FSCalendar, you can show one month or a week .Because of they have the regular :unit.
If you want to show the unregulated days ,you may create custom function.
But I suggest you to use FSCalendar.That's enough.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I knew that I wanted to use FSCalendar but I was unable to do problem which I asked.